# Disable components in a large project

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

with a lot of developers and plenty of juniors I want to disable certain components such as `<p:spacer>` to prohibit using components for html/css issues. I want to limit the available components for libraries like omnifaces / primefaces / richfaces to a whitelist / blacklist thing basically.

Would this be a reasonable feature request for a library like omnifaces or is it to hard to build / to localized?

Comment: e.g PrimeFaces is open source. Why don't you just remove the unwanted components from the sources and build a jar file which is then shared inside your company?

Comment: @stg: I would not do that because you'd have to do the same over and over again with new releases…

Comment: JSF 2, JSF 2.2 or both? Both have considerable/significant differences.

Comment: The tag jsf2 is for jsf 2.x (read its info) and any solution for either version is fine. I really doubt jsf 2.2 added something helpful related to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you can achieve this by providing a custom [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html) implementation (based on [`ApplicationWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/ApplicationWrapper.html)) wherein you override [the desired `createComponent()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/ApplicationWrapper.html#createComponent(javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and throw e.g. `IllegalArgumentException` when a blacklisted component type and/or renderer type is passed.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
public class YourApplication extends ApplicationWrapper {

    private static final Set<String> BLACKLISTED_COMPONENT_TYPES = unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<>(asList(
        "org.primefaces.component.Spacer",
        "com.example.SomeComponentType",
        "com.example.OtherComponentType"
        // Etc..
    )));

    private final Application wrapped;

    public YourApplication(Application wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public UIComponent createComponent(FacesContext context, String componentType, String rendererType) {
        if (BLACKLISTED_COMPONENT_TYPES.contains(componentType)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You are not allowed to use this component.");
        }

        return super.createComponent(context, componentType, rendererType);
    }

    @Override
    public Application getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

}
```

You can get it to run with this factory:

```
public class YourApplicationFactory extends ApplicationFactory {

    private final ApplicationFactory wrapped;

    public YourApplicationFactory(ApplicationFactory wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public Application getApplication() {
        return new YourApplication(wrapped.getApplication());
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplication(Application application) {
        wrapped.setApplication(application);
    }

}
```

Which is registered in `faces-config.xml` as below:

```
<factory>
    <application-factory>com.example.YourApplicationFactory</application-factory>
</factory>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tag file feature of jsf. You will declare tag file for each component that you want to use. After that, your team will only use these tag file in your project.

Comment: Not bad but I like the BalusC solution more