# How to deactivate a JSF tag (Primefaces)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, blacklist

I use Primefaces 5.x (on myFaces 2.2.x) for my UI and I want to disable / deactivate some JSF tags like  to avoid mistakes.

Is there a blacklist or whitelist I can use?

Comment: Maybe a git pre-commit hook to `grep` or `awk`? Just a suggestion -- I haven't tried this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing in standard JSF/PrimeFaces API.

Quick'n'dirty workaround would be overriding the component registration in webapp's `faces-config.xml` whereby you set the component class to a non-`UIComponent` class (it will ultimately throw `ClassCastException` on usage), or to a custom `UIComponent` which throws e.g. `IllegalArgumentException` in its constructor.

E.g. if you'd like to avoid usage of `<p:selectOneMenu>` [component](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/component/selectonemenu/SelectOneMenu.html) which has a [component type of `org.primefaces.component.SelectOneMenu`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/constant-values.html#org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenu.COMPONENT_TYPE):

```
<component>
    <component-type>org.primefaces.component.SelectOneMenu</component-type>
    <component-class>java.lang.Object</component-class>
</component>
```

An alternative would be to [manually visit the component tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29691625/the-earliest-moment-to-visittree-on-fully-built-component-tree/) after it's being built and check every single component class against a white/black list in a `Set<Class<UIComponent>>`.

A more clean alternative would be to [override `Application#createComponent()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560957/disable-components-in-a-large-project) to check the component type against a white/black list.

Yet another alternative would be to edit the PrimeFaces taglib/config XML to remove the undesired components and rebuild the JAR.

Comment: or your own previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560957/disable-components-in-a-large-project

Comment: @Kukeltje: ah, that explains the deja vu I had!

Comment: Me to, but I had to try three different google searches and only found it indirectly

Comment: @Kukeltje: I also couldn't find it. Thank you for finding it, I included it in the answer.